# I want to write a macro that only works in one word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've got this macro in MS Word 2016. It works in every word document, but I want it to work in only one word document eg 'Test.docx'. Can I add something to the code to do this?

The macro in question is this:

```
Sub MyMistakesFinal()
'
' MyMistakesFinal Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find.Font
        .Bold = True
        .Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
    End With
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.Previous(Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Check activedocument.name before hand using IF containing your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test whether the active document is "Test.docx".  If not, exit the sub...

```
Sub MyMistakesFinal()
'
' MyMistakesFinal Macro
'
'
    If ActiveDocument.Name <> " Test.docx" Then Exit Sub

    'etc
    '
    '
    '

End Sub
```